# PHP nested include problem

Tags: php, include

This is engine.php (works fine):

```
<?php
include ('settings/server_settings.php');  
include ('settings/tables.php');  
?>
```

Now i create settings.php in the same folder, and with the same content as engine.php, and then i include this file to engine.php, so i get this:

engine.php:

```
<?php 
include ('settings.php');  
?>
```

settings.php:

```
<?php
include ('settings/server_settings.php');  
include ('settings/tables.php');  
?>
```

And now i dont get any errors (but a random empty(!) line on the top of the page) and i cant use the functions, etc from server_settings.php and tables.php. It seems it fails to include, BUT there are no error message. (In other cases i get error message [misspelling the location, etc])

Whats wrong ?

Comment: Is your error reporting turned on?

Comment: try `require`, so there will be an error if php can't include the files

Comment: Try require instead of include: require('settings.php");

Comment: I had the same problem once, include only worked once. I don't know if it was a typo or a server issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `engine.php` to

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'settings.php';
```

Check your files for a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the top of the file. Some editors (like DreamWeaver) will hide these.

Comment: Converted to UTF-8 without BOM and it saved the day ! Thanks.